# Word order in a sentence with "bitte"

Tags: word-order

Is one of the sentences below incorrect, or is there a preference to one over the other?

> - Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser.
> - Ich möchte ein Glas Wasser bitte.

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that there must be a comma before *bitte* in the second sentence.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: the comma is optional, see my comment below.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich möchte bitte ein Glas Wasser.

This is the standard word order in German, and you sound most fluent when you put it this way.

> Ich möchte ein Glas Wasser[,] bitte.

This is a perfectly valid variant. My suspicion is that in oral communication, the most widespread reason for this being used by native speakers is that they  forgot to add "bitte" earlier. Non-native speakers often use this because it is the standard word order in English, French and other languages.

However, you could also argue that *bitte* is placed at the end of the sentence here to put a bit more emphasis on it; German grammar allows for that.

In writing, you can optionally set a comma before *bitte* (or before and after *bitte* in the first variant).

Comment: I'm not sure regarding the rules but I would be inclined to place a comma before "bitte"  in the second example.

Comment: Please note that in terms of punctuation, the second form requires a comma: "Ein Wasser, bitte!".

Comment: Please note that also "Bitte, ein Glas Wasser!" would work. But I agree that the most fluent form is the first one.

Comment: @Roland, Nils Magnus: the comma is optional. https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D131, https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bitte